# Open Tabs in browser and have their Instance C#

Tags: c#, url

I have a windows application in C#.
I would like to open about 5 application (urls) in web browser (best IE), each in different tab. During the program is working this URLs will change and I want to open this links like:

1. if for example first application is still open then only reload page
   in the same tab.
2. if appliaction is closed than open new tab

Comment: Browsers don't have APIs for this, there is no fool-proof way to do what you want. As with your previous questions about this same subject, can't you change the approach altogether? Use a WebBrowser _in_ your application which you use to display the sites you want?

Comment: Once you've launched a browser window, users expect to "own" it - they don't expect programs to assume that they can continue to manipulate it or "decide" on the user's experience for them.

Comment: Are the 5 websites yours? Your question is very unclear. `if for example first application is still open then only reload page in the same tab` - what does this mean?

Comment: You can write an extension for the web browser, so the extension will do the work. And you can manage this extension to open/refresh tabs from some server. I'm not sure this whole idea is possible to implement, just thoughts.